# Use Wordpress Shortcodes on html page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am developing an application for my radio station using phonegap and I am trying to figure out a few things. Like how do I use shortcodes from the wordpress in html file for phone gap. The music player for the application is on the website

https://takeovaradio.trillumonopoly.com

and I need to put just that element into the html files for phonegap.
Please help

I did it using an iframe but It left an unwanted border not filling the screen from edge to edge and it didnt play.... please help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
do_shortcode()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Where/if that doesn't work, try:

```
apply_filters()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/